# Is there an equivalent of WaitUntil() from Unity3D in VS?

Tags: c#, multithreading

In Unity3D, there are coroutines where you could call `WaitUntil()` until the statement becomes true, such as when a string is not empty.

```
string str="";
yield return new WaitUntil(()=>str!="");
```

I find it very useful and would like to employ it in VS.

I managed to do it by creating 2 classes, say A and B,

```
class A
{
    public B b;

    public void Set(B bb)
    {
        b = bb;
        b.Str = "Test";
        b.ARE.Set();
    }
}

class B
{
    public string Str="";
    public AutoResetEvent ARE = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public B()
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(Run);
        t.Start();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        ARE.WaitOne();
        MessageBox.Show(String.Format($"The new string is {Str}");
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    a.Set(b);
}
```

As you can see, the execution of B relies on A setting B's `AutoResetEvent`.

Is there a way to let B handles it by itself?

I had done some research on the subject of `Task.WhenAll` and the others, but I don't really know how to use it and in the end, I think `AutoResetEvent` is more appropriate for the job. But of course, I could be wrong!

PS. I'm trying to avoid things like `while(Str=="");` because it's processing heavy!

Even though it's run on a different thread, it will still occupy unnecessary memory and processing power.

So I would like to postpone it altogether if possible until the condition to continue is met.

Thank you very much for your help!

Much appreciated!

Comment: how about: `while(Str=="") await Task.Delay(1);` or `while(Str=="") Thread.Sleep(1);` ? since you'll need a endless loop anyway and to relax the cpu just wait in between the checks

Comment: ＠PatrickBeynio It might help a little bit, but I still like to avoid it altogether if possible! Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: *"I find it very useful and would like to employ it in VS."* What is the VS?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Visual Studio

Answer (score 0):

I am not an Unity expert but from what I understand, Unity calls `Update()` function at each frame of the game. Also based on the documentation, it looks like this (Unity):

```
yield return WaitUntil(() => condition);
```

Is the same as this (pure C#):

```
while (!condition)
    yield return null;
```

Without detailing the mighty `yield` keyword, both these return an `IEnumerator`. Each time you "move [to the] next" value of the iterator, the function is executed and the next value is returned. `MoveNext()` will return `true` as long as there are values to be returned, including `null`.

Basically, `WaitUntil()` seems to be some sort of Unity dialect for something equivalent in pure C#. I suspect things like `StartCoroutine()` to be a similar mechanism of starting a thread (*not sure about this one*).

Here is a working program that attempts to explain what happens:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        private static int frameCounter;

        public class B
        {
            public string MyString { get; set; }

            public IEnumerator Run()
            {
                while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(MyString))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Nothing here yet..."); // This is printed every time MoveNext() is called on the iterator.
                    yield return null;
                }

                // MyString is not null anymore: print this.
                // This is also the end of the enumerator: no more values will be returned.
                Console.WriteLine("MyString has been set after we " + MyString);
            }
        }

        public static void Main()
        {
            // This simulates Unity's engine by generating one frame every 500ms.
            var frameTimer = new Timer(_ => UpdateFrameCounter(), null, 0, 500);

            // Creates an instance of B and get the enumerator by calling Run():
            var b = new B();
            var enumerator = b.Run();

            // As long as there are values being returned (by yield), stay in this loop.
            // Here, this means basically "as long as b.MyString is null or empty".
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                // Demo purposes: block main thread for 1sec.
                Thread.Sleep(1000);

                // At frame 10, set the value of b.MyString
                if (frameCounter == 10)
                {
                    b.MyString = "reached 10 frames.";
                }
            }

            // We'll reach this when there are no more values to be returned, i.e. enumerator.MoveNext() == false.
            // Stop the timer and quit.
            frameTimer.Change(Timeout.Infinite, Timeout.Infinite);
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to quit...");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void UpdateFrameCounter()
        {
            // Update frame counter (-> Unity engine).
            Console.WriteLine($"Frame counter: {++frameCounter}");
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
To use exactly your example, you can set `b.Str` as a property then reset the event in there:

```
// In class B:
private string str = string.Empty; // private field

public string Str // public property
{ 
    get => str;
    set 
    { 
        str = value;
        ARE.Set(); // this is called each time b.Str value is set
    }
}
```

This way, when A or any other class sets the value of b.Str, `ARE` will be automatically set without A having to worry or know about it.